# How to create new custom View(UserControl)? AvalonDock

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, avalondock

I use the perfect library AvalonDock and I notice that Text Document is created when clicking "File->New" in the run program. However, I would like to create not Text Document, but some UserControl with my buttons and its viewmodel.

I've found a code creating new text documents:

```
private void OnNew(object parameter)
{
   _files.Add(new FileViewModel());
   ActiveDocument = _files.Last();
}
```

**Now:**
[image]

**Want to implement:**
[image]

This code creates TextDocument
 Is it possible? Do you have some tutorial how to implement it?

My questions is **how to create UserControl instead of Text document with ViewModel**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was really simple. If I replace `TextBox` in `DataTemplate` by `UserControl` called `SomeUserControl`, it is really replaced by `UserControl` and I can insert any controls:

```
<Window x:Class="AvalonDock.MVVMTestApp.NewWindow"
    ....
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AvalonDock.MVVMTestApp">

  <avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplateSelector>
    <local:PanesTemplateSelector>
      <local:PanesTemplateSelector.FileViewTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <!--<TextBox Text="{Binding TextContent, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>-->            
           <local:SomeUserControl/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </local:PanesTemplateSelector.FileViewTemplate>      
    .....                               
  </avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplateSelector>
</Window>
```

AvalonDock is really cool docking windows control!

Answer (score 1):

[GEMINI](https://github.com/tgjones/gemini) is an good example.

You can do it by using StyleSelector and DataTemplateSelector.

Comment: https://github.com/tgjones/gemini/blob/master/src/Gemini/Modules/Shell/Views/ShellView.xaml

Comment: I can use StyleSelector and DataTemplateSelector in AvalonDock or in gemini? I've tried to run Gemini, but there are no projects which can be compiled. Please, show compiled example.

Comment: https://github.com/AizazAhmed/AvalonEdit clone this project, compile it and add the missing reference. The Gemini is an good example for visual studio type IDE.